# how to redirect based on country's IP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using polylang plugin to make a multilanguage site on WordPress.

As Wordpress detect the language as per browser's setting, every time I browse my website defaults in English language but I want to display my website in my country's language by default, later on, I can switch back to the English language if need from language switcher. So without the use of any plugin, I want to write some PHP code.

I have done something like this on index.php file without success 'Page is not working on browser',

any help would be appreciated !!

Here is the code

```
<?php
  $a = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
  $countrycode= $a['geoplugin_countryCode'];
  if ($countrycode=='myCountryCode')
     header( 'Location: http://domainname/wordpress/' ) ;
  else
     header( 'Location: http://domainname/wordpress/index.php/en/' ) ;    

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);*/

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Here are the values I am getting for some variables:

```
 $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] -> 198.16.66.XXX
 $a -> Array
 $countrycode -> NL
```

Comment: please try printing the values for $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and $a and see if they are missing something. add those to your post too.

Comment: The issue was because of redirecting to same location, when I tried to redirect to some other site it worked and this is what redirect is for. Now I want some other solution for this.

Comment: Sounds like you should simply check what URL you are currently on, _before_ you try to redirect to that same location again … Btw., making an HTTP request to an external service for every single request is a rather bad idea, in terms of performance. And should the external service ever be “down”, your whole page would likely “hang” as well (at least until that HTTP request times out.) This should really rather use a local IP geo database.

Comment: @04FS Redirect cannot be bad idea as you are saying because it can be used in many cases like displaying the content or pages per country specific. By the way, the issue get resolved for me without writing any script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple, as I had used polylang for multilinguel support, I made it work by deactivating the Detect Browser Language Settings.